# ALTER postgres table owned by user from the same group

Tags: postgresql

There are plenty of similar questions, but I'm still unable to understand something simple about postgres ALTER, DROP, roles and permissions.

I want to have a DB with multiple users belonging to the same group. When one of the users creates a table, others should be able to use it as if they created it themselves. I can make it work to some extent, but the ALTER and DROP remain a mystery.

For example, starting from scratch I create a database with two users:

```
CREATE DATABASE test_db;
\c test_db 

CREATE ROLE alice LOGIN INHERIT;
CREATE ROLE bjork LOGIN INHERIT;
```

Then I create a group and assign users to the group:

```
CREATE ROLE scientists;
GRANT scientists TO alice;
GRANT scientists TO bjork;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE alice GRANT ALL ON TABLES to scientists;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE bjork GRANT ALL ON TABLES to scientists;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT ALL ON TABLES to scientists;
```

`alice` creates a table:

```
\c - alice
CREATE TABLE test_table (column_a TEXT);
```

`bjork` can read, write, but can't neither `ALTER`, nor `DROP`:

```
\c - bjork 
ALTER TABLE test_table ADD COLUMN column_b TEXT;
ERROR:  must be owner of relation test_table
```

`SET`'ing `ROLE` to `scientists` doesn't help either (and it shouldn't, because `INHERIT`)

```
set role scientists;
ALTER TABLE test_table ADD COLUMN column_b TEXT;
ERROR:  must be owner of relation test_table
```

What am I missing? Is it even possible to have `test_table` owned by `alice` and `ALTER`'ed by `bjork`?

Comment: I think you (also) need `alter default privileges in schema public grant all on tables to scientists;`  otherwise newly created tables won't get the default privileges

Comment: why you just don't create a schema for the user `scientists` with authorization and put all tables there - then all scientists will have grant to alter the tables. Or alter default privilages on public schema.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried (see edited question where I inserted the statement), it still does not seem to work.

Comment: @JustMe Could you please give a hint on how to alter the privileges? In my real db I do have separate schema, but I am unable to set it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `SET ROLE` *before* you create the table, so that the role becomes the table owner.

Only the table owner is allowed to `ALTER` the table.

Comment: So you are saying that there is no way to have `test_table` owned by `alice` and `ALTER`'ed by `bjork`? Executing `SET ROLE` before creating table is cumbersome, and I was hoping that scientists would not need to care about such things.

Comment: Yes, it is like that. Are people really using the database interactively? If not, your application could execute the `SET ROLE` after login.

Comment: I see. I will find a way how to deal with the `SET ROLE` then. Thanks for help!